# Animate background colors in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I currently have a static background colour:

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

How would I code to create a series of animated colours over a set number of seconds (for example 5 seconds per colour) and then return to the beginning of the colour loop?

I've tried the following...

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0);
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
})
```

...but this just stays on the last blue colour.

Answer (score 2):

You must make a nested animation

```
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0);
    },
     completion: { finished in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }, completion: { finished in
            //other color do the same
        })

    })
```

Comment: Exactly. CoreAnimation interpolates the animatable properties between their current values, and the final ones which are determined after the execution of the animation block.

Note also that if block argument `finished` is not used, you might be better off with `completion: { _ in ... }`.

Comment: The code in the nested animation above goes straight to the last colour (blue) and stays there without the animation between the previous colours.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
    let maxNumberOfRepeats = 10
    var currentNumberOfRepeats = 0
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) { timer in
        currentNumberOfRepeats = currentNumberOfRepeats + 1
        if currentNumberOfRepeats == maxNumberOfRepeats {
            timer.invalidate()
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { 
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0) //return to first color
            })
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0) //or any other random color
            })
        }
    }
```